# Query custom post type by custom taxonomy (category slug)

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, query

I've followed several related solution. But I'm still facing the problem.
I've applied the following code for my custom post query by taxonomy (category). But it's not working. I think my problem with 'terms'.

```
$terms = get_terms('service_cat');
$services_post = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'service',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'service_cat',
            'field' => 'cat1',
            'terms' => $terms
        )
    ),
));
```

I also tried by the following code

```
$services_post = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type'         => 'service',
            'posts_per_page'    => -1,
            'category_name'     => 'cat1' 
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited to reflect question in OP's comment.*

The contents of the [`tax_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) array are not exactly right: as you're querying by slug, the `field` parameter of the individual taxonomy query should be `"slug"`.

You're currently basically querying for all `service` posts from all service categories (well, not even that, because `get_terms` returns objects, but still).

To query for a single (or more than one) specific terms from which to load posts, specify the terms in the `terms` array. `tax_query` is then parsed accordingly.

```
$services_post = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'         => 'service',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'service_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'cat1' ) // Array of service categories you wish to retrieve posts from
        )
    )
) );
```

By the way, I am assuming you want to retrieve all posts of post type `service`

Comment: Your code only showing posts that have at least one service category.
But I want to show posts by specific category slug.
Can you help me about that please?

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the information from your comment.